# Connect to Windows Server 2016 SMB share from CentOS - session setup failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: smbclient

I tired to mount a Windows SMB share in Linux using autofs, but I kept getting 'access denied'

I decided to test it using smbclient, but I am just getting 'session setup failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET'.

```
sudo smbclient //myfileserver/myshare$ -U windows_service_account -W MYDOMAIN
```

There shouldn't be a firewall and the errors aren't very helpful.

Any idea what to check next?

Answer (score 0):

2016 blocks v1 SMB by default.

Perhaps enable that on the Windows Server (less secure...not great) or change smbclient to use minimum version 2.

Just a guess though.....

Also, wasnt sure how to tell you to change the version in CentOS so here you go:

Edit smb.conf file, run:
$ sudo vi /etc/samba/smb.conf

Find the [global] section and append the following line:
min protocol = SMB2

From here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configure-samba-to-use-smbv2-and-disable-smbv1-on-linux-or-unix/

Answer (score 0):

Removing -W resolved the issue